# File server does not show new files unless I copy and paste inside that folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a LAN file server here that we access with Windows Explorer and for some reason I can't see new files or folders.

Just pressing F5 doesn't update what's in the folder normally.

The only thing that works is if I delete something or copy and paste something there and then refresh with F5.

I've also tried manually changing the directory to the folder by typing it in the file path explorer. That doesn't work unless I copy and paste and then refresh.

If it matters the file server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Does the problem occur in safe mode with networking?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I'm not sure. I'll have to test tomorrow morning when a new folder pops up! I'll let you know!! Thanks :)

Comment: It's kind of random when it happens. It didn't happen today. I'll keep trying and let you know.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It's difficult to tell because restarting the computer in general sometimes updates the folder. So I'm not sure if safemode is affecting it at all.

Comment: Hmm...how about in a new user account on the client PC? Or in [Clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) mode?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I can try both. Since it's random it will take me some time to verify but I will get back to you. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Offline Files may be your culprit. Try disabling it.

Offline Files periodically tests the latency and bandwidth of the connection to the file server. If it falls below a (configurable) threshold, Windows will either put the share into Background Sync mode, or if it's bad enough, mark the remote share as offline. Specifically the former case will lead to the behavior you're experiencing.

Offline Files is useful for servers you don't have a reliable, high-speed connection to. It's even useful in specific cases where you *do* have a fast connection. However, sometimes it causes trouble and disabling it is a perfectly acceptable solution.

Comment: I had to un-accept your answer because it was just a fluke. I still have to copy, paste, delete, then push F5 on most days to get new folders to appear. Any other ideas?

Comment: @LateralTerminal that's too bad. I'll comment on the OP since this remains a valid answer for others with this problem.